# What is the difference between the classification and the pattern recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, dataset, pattern-recognition

Could somebody explain this difference just as simple as possible?

Answer (score 3):

*Pattern recognition* is the “automated discovery of patterns in a training set”, and so it is a general term for machine learning.

*Classification* is the *supervised learning* problem whose target value is a finite set of classes (as opposed to *regression*, wherein the target value is a continuous variable).

Therefore, classification is a kind of pattern recognition problem.

Comment: well stated: I had not considered `pattern recognition` to be nearly synonymous with ML

Comment: @javadba To be honest, I lifted that from Bishop's introduction in “Pattern recognition and machine learning”.

Answer (score -1):

Classification is simply a more general term than pattern recognition. In both cases, you have a set of classes $K$ and a collection of observations, where each observation is represented by a set of features. Your job is to find a mapping of features to a member of $K$ such that you minimize some measure/estimate of out-of-sample classification error.

In pattern recognition, you are simply using a very complex/large feature space. For example, facial recognition will have an input space equal to the number of pixels in the image. This is no different than classifying a loan application as high or low risk based on several measures of creditworthiness.

Comment: Pattern recognition is a more general term.